# Arduino Bluetooth connection gives me uploading error

Tags: error-handling, upload, arduino, arduino-uno

İt's a simple basic thing in which i have my arduino connected to a HC-06 bluetooth. The point is to control switch on/off led pin with my phone. Here's the code :

```
int ledPin = 13;
int state = 0;
int flag = 0;

 void setup() {
 pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
 Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() >0) {
   state = Serial.read();
   flag = 0;
 }

  if(state == '0') {
   digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    Serial.println("LED: off");
     flag = 1;
   }
 }

 else if (state == '1') {
   Serial.println("LED: on");
   flag = 1; 
 }
```

}
I don't think it might have much relevance. Whenever i try to upload the code it gives me the following error:

```
avrdude stk500_recv() programmer is not responding
avrdude stk500_getsync() attempt # of 10 not in sync resp=0x00
```

Any idea why and how i might solve it. 
Thnx in advance!
Douglas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that there is a conflict between the USB/Serial and HC06/Serial.

You can solve this issue by using the [Software Serial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) library and connect the HC06 to other pins. You can find an example [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SoftwareSerialExample) on how to use the library.

Answer (score 0):

Unplug the rx and tx pins and keep in power and ground while uploading. When these pins are connected it interferes with the program's ability to upload. If this is in fact the problem then once the program is uploaded you can reattach rx and tx. Now you should be able to properly pair to your device.

Answer (score 0):

Please disconnect the Tx and RX pin from Arduino before uploading and connect it after uploading the code. Otherwise, it will show an error